# C++ Lambda - Loop over integer array

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to loop over an integer array using a lambda template.

The code to invoke the lambda would look something like this **(demo purposes, not functional code)**:

```
menu.option("Set Pedestrian Health to 0").allpeds(ped => {
     SET_ENTITY_HEALTH(ped, 0);
});
```

The problem: how would I make the `allpeds` lambda template?

`allpeds` would loop over an array of unique integers representing a pedestrian in the game.

I have this code so far:

```
template<typename T> Menu& allpeds() {
    if (pressed()) {
        int numElements = 20;
        int arrSize = numElements * 2 + 2;

        int peds[arrSize];
        peds[0] = numElements;

        int countPeds = PED::GET_PED_NEARBY_PEDS(playerPed, peds, -1);

        for (int i = 0; i < countPeds; i++) {
            int ped = peds[i * 2 + 2];

            // if this is the right way to do it,
            // how to put `ped` in an integer array, and return it
            // so I can use it in the lambda template?
        }
    }

    //return *this;
}
```

I'm trying to keep the code as C as possible.

If more explanation is needed, please let me know!

Comment: Why do you want to keep the code as close to C if you're using C++?  `template`s and lambdas already have you pretty far away from C.

Comment: Your first example indicates to me that `allpeds` should be taking an argument, but your comments in the function sound like you want to do something else. You should really clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: @UnholySheep Don't mind the second snippet - it was my design attempt at making the first snippet work. If the first snippet works I'm a happy man

Comment: That doesn't really make it clearer whether `allpeds` should be taking an argument or not, what "integer array" you want to return (or where to) or what "lambda template" you are referring to. Usually I'd assume that you want to take a "functor" argument and call that inside the loop, but the rest of the question makes me very unsure whether that is really what you want

Comment: My feeling is that it would be worth reading about C++ lambdas, as the syntax shown is not how you do lambdas in C++. And if you really want it to be a lambda and not just a class member function, for whatever reason, my other feeling is that you'd want `std::for_each()`. But the code given does not constitute a great [mre], making it very difficult to recommend anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have shown is more C# than C++, as far as the lambda syntax is concerned.  But even then, the example is clearly passing the lambda as a parameter to `allpeds()`, and the lambda itself takes an input parameter, too. `allpeds()` is not returning an array that the lambda then iterates, `allpeds()` calls the lambda passing it each integer value as needed.

In C++, you can use something like this:

```cpp
menu.option("Set Pedestrian Health to 0").allpeds(
    [](int ped) {
        SET_ENTITY_HEALTH(ped, 0);
    }
);
```

```cpp
template<typename FuncType>
Menu& allpeds(FuncType func) {
    if (pressed()) {
        int numElements = 20;
        int arrSize = numElements * 2 + 2;

        std::vector<int> peds(arrSize);
        peds[0] = numElements;

        int countPeds = PED::GET_PED_NEARBY_PEDS(playerPed, peds.data(), -1);

        for (int i = 0; i < countPeds; ++i) {
            int ped = peds[i * 2 + 2];
            func(ped);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: That is so great! Very awesome! Thanks Remy for the help big time!